# How to do custom Binding on JAVA (Netbeans IDE)

Tags: java, netbeans, binding

I want to find out how to do custom binding on java, I've searching on google but not found any. 
It's simple problem,
I have two `jSpinner`, `jSpin1` and `jSpin2`.
`jSpin2` value is half from `jSpin1`.

when I do binding, there is

```
Binding source : jSpin1
Binding expression : ${value}
```

so the value in `jSpin2` exactly the same with `jSpin1`. then how could I make its value half from  `jSpin1`?

thank you.

Comment: Don't always depend on drag'n'Drop of IDE's, do some of your custom coding also. It is not going to be very difficult..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I Understand you use NetBeans GUI Builder. You can do it by the next steps:

- do right click on jSpin2 (in design view) and select ‘Properties’

- select ‘Binding’ at the top of dialog

- click on ‘...’ button on ‘value’ property

- select ‘jSpin1’ from ‘Binding Source’

- select ‘value’ from ‘Binding Expression’

- edit ‘Binding Expression’ to ‘${value/2}’

(Also you can put ‘jSpin1[${value/2}]’ in ‘value’ property)